# Display Separator only for the Available CellForRow in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, ios9

I am using UITableView with custom cell. 
It is working fine but problem is when there is only one or two cell in UITableView.
It is giving the separator for the empty cell also.
Is it possible to display separator only for the cell that is load with my custom cell?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add an empty footer view to hide empty rows from a table.

**Swift:**

In your `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.tblPeopleList.tableFooterView = UIView.init()
```

**Objective-C:**

**Easiest way:**

in your `viewDidLoad` method,

```
self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectZero];
```

**or**

```
self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

**or**

If you want to customize the look of footer view, you can do it like this.

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = view;

//OR add an image in footer
//UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:footerImage.png]
//imageView.frame = table.frame;
//self.yourTableView.tableFooterView = imageView;
```

**Another way:**

Implement data source method of a table,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [UIView new];
}
```

It's the same thing, but here you can add different views for each section if the table has multiple sections. Even you can set different height of each section with this method, `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {...}`.

<sup>**Objective-C Answer Note**: This answer is tested for iOS7 and above, for the previous versions you've to test each case.</sup>
<sup>**Swift Answer Note**: This answer is tested for iOS10.3 and above, for the previous versions you've to test each case.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Another solution:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:v];
```

This works too

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this peace of code in your viewDidLoad

```
self.tblTest.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectZero];
```

Comment: This code works perfectly in both iOS 7 and 8. you don't need to clear  the color of background view.