# Is it possible to add blank space to the end of a tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make a tableview that has blank space at the end of it so that the user can scroll up more and display the last cells more in focus. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean like a footer view?

Comment: Use a footer or simply an empty cell.

Comment: I think, you're asking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445775/display-separator-only-for-the-available-cellforrow-in-uitableview/15445781#15445781).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes: [`tableFooterView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableFooterView), but you should never need to.

Here is a sample of how to use `tableFooterView`:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
// configure view as needed
self.tableView.tableFooterView = view;
```

What you should look into is [`contentInset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset):

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 0.0)];
```

Hope that helps.